# Want file download in asp.net to be detectable by download managers like idm,dap?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Here is my code

```
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView2WordMethod2.doc");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
//Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
exportGrdVw.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
frm.Controls.Add(exportGrdVw);
frm.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

It is working and downloading contents of a gridview to Doc file but it is downloading using chrome default download manager . I want it to be detectable by Download managers like IDM ,DAp etc.

Please help

Comment: check for multiple connection to same file! IDM & FDM applications use `Range` header to download files in multiple part at same time!